# set size of image with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML that contains img tag

```
<xml>
<img src="/path/to/file.jpg" orginalwidth="150" />
</xml>
```

I want to have:

```
<img src="/paht/to/file.jpg" size=SIZE />
```

Where SIZE is minimum of orginalsize and 100px

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete and short solution and an explanation how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pmaxSize" select="100"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@orginalwidth">
  <xsl:attribute name="size">
   <xsl:value-of select=".*not(. > $pmaxSize) + $pmaxSize*(. > $pmaxSize)"/>
   <xsl:text>px</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when performed on the provided XML document**:

```
<xml>
 <img src="/path/to/file.jpg" orginalwidth="150" />
</xml>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<xml>
    <img src="/path/to/file.jpg" size="100px"/>
</xml>
```

**when applied on the following XML document**:

```
<xml>
 <img src="/path/to/file.jpg" orginalwidth="99" />
</xml>
```

**the result is again the wanted and correct one**:

```
<xml>
    <img src="/path/to/file.jpg" size="99px"/>
</xml>
```

**Explanation**:

In XPath 1.0 any boolean value, when used as a number is converted from `true()` to `1` and from `false()` to `0`.

Therefore, the expression:

```
.*not(. > $pmaxSize) + $pmaxSize*(. > $pmaxSize)
```

evaluates to `.` if `.` is less or equal `$pmaxSize` and to `$pmaxSize` otherwize.

`.` is the value of the current node interpreted as number.

Comment: +1 Better and compact expression with numbers intead of strings

Comment: Off topic. `xquery` questions are growing. Maybe you would like to revisit them.

Comment: Is it possible to find orginal size of image without extra parameter (orginal size). I mean always display image in its normal size except when its greater than max?

Comment: @liysd: Original size isn't parameter here. max is. If you don't want to use a parameter at all, you can hardcode it -- just change `<xsl:param>` to `<xsl:variable>`

Answer (score 3):

Using XSLT 1.0 (XSLT 2.0 probably gives you other options, but not sure if you are in a position to use it):

```
<img src="{@src}">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@originalsize &lt; 100">
        <xsl:attribute name="size"><xsl:value-of select="@originalsize"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:attribute name="size">100</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</img>
```

Comment: select cannot be in xsl:attribute

Answer (score 1):

Whenever is posible to use literal result elements an attributes value templaes, do use it.

```
<img src="{@src}" size="{substring('100',
                                   1 div (@orginalwidth > 100))
                       }{substring(@orginalwidth,
                                   1 div not(@orginalwidth > 100))
                       }px"/>
```

**EDIT**: Minimum not maximum, sorry.